# Receiving a value-of-reference error when passing around variables using pass-by-reference

Tags: c++, constants, pass-by-reference

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

const int OPERAND_RANGE = 100;

void doOneProblem(char &op);
void doOneSet(char &op);
void generateOperands(int &num1, int &num2);
void calculateAnswer(int &num1, int &num2, int &answer, char &op);
void checkAnswer(int num1, int num2, int &answer, int &userAnswer, char &op);

int main() {

    srand(static_cast<unsigned>(time(0)));
    doOneSet('+');

}

void generateOperands(int &num1, int &num2) {

    num1 = rand() % (OPERAND_RANGE + 1);
    num2 = rand() % (OPERAND_RANGE + 1);

}

void calculateAnswer(int &num1, int &num2, int &answer, int &userAnswer, char &op) {

    if (op == '+') {
        answer = num1 + num2;
    } else if (op == '-') {
        answer = num1 - num2;
    } else if (op == '*') {
        answer = num1 * num2;
    } else if (op == '/') {
        answer = num1 / num2;
    } else {
        cout << "Not an accepted operator.";
    }

}

void doOneProblem(char &op) {

    int num1, num2, answer, userAnswer;
    char op;

    generateOperands(num1, num2);
    calculateAnswer(num1, num2, answer, userAnswer, op);
    checkAnswer(num1, num2, answer, userAnswer, op);


}

void checkAnswer(int num1, int num2, int &answer, int &userAnswer, char &op) {

    cout << "What is " << num1 << " " << op << " " << num2 << "?: " << endl;
    cin >> userAnswer;

    if (userAnswer == answer) {
        cout << "Correct!" << endl;
    } else {
        cout << "Incorrect" << endl;
    }


}

void doOneSet(char &op) {

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

        doOneProblem(op);

    }


}
```

Hey everyone, I'm doing some practice with pass-by-reference variables. when I call the function doOneSet in main, I get the error:

```
initial value of reference to non-const must be an lvalue
```

My goal is to pass the operator (op) variable from the doOneSet all the way back to the calculateAnswer() function which should determine the answer based on the char entered.

Error message:

```
a7_1.cpp:18:5: error: no matching function for
      call to 'doOneSet'
    doOneSet('+');
    ^~~~~~~~
a7_1.cpp:10:6: note: candidate function not
      viable: expects an l-value for 1st
      argument
void doOneSet(char &op);
     ^
1 error generated.
```

Comment: For convenience please add in what line the error occurs.

Comment: `'+'` is a `const char`, not a `char`. NB Your method `doOneProblem(char &op)` also declares a local `char op` variable. Remove it.

Answer (score 0):

When you do this:

```
doOneSet('+');
```

on this function:

```
void doOneProblem(char &op);
```

You are making a non-const reference to an `rvalue`. How does the compiler know that in that function you won't do this:

```
op = 10;
```

And if you did, what would happen? Where does the rvalue op exist and what would you be changing? The solution is to specify the prototype of the function correctly. For this case it should be:

```
 void doOneProblem(char op);
```

Comment: thank you for that. However I still get the same error when I fixed the function. I'll add the error message to the post. EDIT: Fixed it. I made the variable in doOneSet a pass-by-value. NO idea why that worked, but it did.

Comment: @JulianL When you fixed the function how? You need to make the parameter `const char &op`, and the same in all other functions where it occurs. But why you're passing primitives around by reference at all is a mystery. The only one that needs to be by reference is `answer`, and you could always make that a return value instead.

Comment: @EJP I would LOVE to use return values. It would be way easier. However, this is for my CS class and our professor is trying to teach us how to use pass-by-reference, so return values are not allowed.